# PowerBI Data Refresh Error: TEAuthTokenExpired. Please update the token and try again

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-datasource

I have two sources (Azure Databrick, SQL Server) for my report. My report uses merge to combine both sources.
I can see data has been loaded but after sometime it fails and throws this error:
TEAuthTokenExpired. Please update the token and try again..